# Get the Average of a Column made by Group By Date()

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(Time)
FROM  tablename
WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-12-23' GROUP BY DATE(Time)
```

This query returns something like :

```
COUNT(Time)
'302'
'1322'
'145'
'670'
'1091'
'589'
'1101'
'324'
```

How may i edit the query to return the average among this values ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative way that doesn't require a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(Time) / count(distinct DATE(Time))
FROM  tablename
WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-12-23';
```

This manually calculates the average by taking the overall total and dividing by the number of times.

Comment: Thank you for this both works but from your expertise, which is better performance wise ?

Comment: @user3066913 . . . The best way to answer this question is to test it.  However, the distinct should be slightly better.  MySQL materializes the subquery in the `group by` method.  It does similar processing for the `count(distinct)`, but does not actually need to materialize the subquery.

Comment: +1 Gordon Linoff @user3066913 see (note demo case) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59ccc8/1 this query should be the fasted based on the explain and thoery -> "Using temporary; Using filesort" are known to slowdown execution on large datasets but both methods would require an full index scan what can be just as bad as an full table scan depends on the data size within the index. So both methods would give the same performance on smaller datasets..

Answer (score 3):

```
select avg(cnt_time)
from
(
   SELECT COUNT(Time) as cnt_time
   FROM  tablename
   WHERE DATE(Time) BETWEEN '2013-07-14' and '2013-12-23' 
   GROUP BY DATE(Time)
) alias_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) It works. But to avoid sub queries, i will use the second.

Comment: +1 juergen d @user3066913 subqueries are not always bad.. derived tables are powerfull like the one in this anwser and should NOT be avoided... You SHOULD avoid the so called `correlated subqueries` at ALL costs these are known to throw MySQL into suidical mode with large datasets..